# Metro-style apps UI types

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Does Metro-style apps UI only support either Fullscreen or tile-based environment?
Is there any other window styles?

Comment: There are 2 other snap configurations as well, in which it occupies 1/3rd and 2/3rd of the screen.

Comment: And there a number of clipped configurations when the touch keyboard squishes your app into the top part of the screen. Please describe the practical programming problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

"Metro" or Windows Store applications support several [orientations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayorientations.aspx) and [layout states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewstate.aspx). Depending on the resolution of your device, Filled and Snapped may or may not be available (1366 x 768 or greater resolution is required).

Within an application you can also use flyouts (such as provided by the [Callisto library](https://github.com/timheuer/Callisto) for XAML applications and included 'natively' for JavaScript).

Tiles are not really an application 'style.' Every Windows Store application can have a tile on the Start Screen, and it's part of your application's manifest to determine the appearance (though the user has ultimate control over the size and whether he/she wants the tile on the Start Screen at all).  Additionally, through the use of [notifications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/02/windows-8-notifications-overview.aspx) you can reflect additional information via the tile, but again you can't rely on the tile actually being there even if your application is installed.